# given a graph (or metagraph) (but no TF event files), how to visualize it

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

For visualization a computation graph, I guess TensorBoard is the right tool. (Right?)

Now I have the computation graph (or meta graph), stored on disk (but not TF event log files). How can I visualize the computation graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `.pb` file, check [import_pb_to_tensorboard.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py).

If it is a `.meta`, the idea is to create an event file:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('meta_folder/model.meta')  # load meta
saver.restore(sess, ckpt_folder)  # load ckpt
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir=event_folder, graph=tf.get_default_graph())  # write to event
writer.flush()
```

Hope this helps as I do not have a `.meta` at hand to test.